# understanding of imread in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to reimplement the matlab code in python, however I have never done matlab code, so can someone help me to understand it, the code is shown below

```
 img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lJw8.png');  % read the image
depth = double(img(:,:,1));
depth(depth==255)=-100;  % make the background VERY distinct
[dy dx] = gradient(depth);  % compute depth gradients
bmsk = sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2) > 5;  % consider only significant gradient
```

firstly what does ' `depth = double(img(:,:,1))`' output, since img is a matrix, img(:,:1) is a matrix with width*height*256?

secondly, `depth(depth==255)=-100` , does it mean when the depth value of one pixal equals to 255, then the value of this pixel minus 100?

Comment: The command `double(...)` is a cast which converts the values (in the matrix `img` representing red) to doubles. I would assume that the Matrix `img` has the format N-by-M-by-3 (represting red green blue). And you interpreted the second command correctly. Here logical indexing `depth==255` is used to overwrite all values which are equal to `255` with `-100`

Comment: Looking at your image, I would use `rgb2gray` and work with the grayscale image instead of just using the red channel

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki But computationally, which would you rather do: compute `depth = 0.2989 * img(:,:,1) + 0.5870 * img(:,:,2) + 0.1140 * img(:,:,3)` or copy the first `height*width` elements of the image using `depth = img(:,:,1)`?

Comment: Unless the image is huge and I have to process millions of them I'd still make sure I have a good representation of the luminosity instead of just taking one color channel. Also if computation resources are critical I'd do some hacks in the code (eg: getting rid of the sqrt to compute the distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is coloring image, it would be `width*height*3` which 3 is for RGB channels. Hence, `img(:,:,1)` means red channel of the `img`, and its dimension is `width*height`. As, `img` is `uint8` (unsigned int 8 bit), to compute an algorithm on real values, we use `double` to change its data type to `double` from `uint8`.

When we write `depth(depth == 255) = -100` means we replace all `255` values in `depth` replaced by `-100`. The question is what happened and why we do this? As, you want to save the final result in image which is `uint8`, all values normalized from 0 to 255. Therefore, if the maximum value in depth after this substitution in 150 and minimum value would be -100, in final result, -100 pixels values would be 0, 100 pixel values would be `fix(100*255/150) = 170`, and 150 would 255.